# Loading a .NET DLL from Resources inside a Win32/clr DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c++-cli

I wrote a **Win32-DLL** (with clr support in VS 2010/13, c++) as extension for another/old VB6 app and use the opensource-dll PDFSharp.

It works fine, but if the "PDFSharp.dll" removed from Directory the Application crashes if the program try to load my dll.
I want to include the Sharp DLL into mine, so that only one **DLL** is needed.
I tried to add it to resources, and load/catch the error during run time by

```
AppDomain^ root = AppDomain::CurrentDomain;

root->CurrentDomain->AssemblyResolve += gcnew ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);
```

in the first Function that the app calls, but my Problem is, the app/dll crashes before i can handle something.

ILMerge can't help, because it is a Win32/net(clr) DLL not a 100% NET-DLL.

Comment: Does the C# reference the mixed-mode DLL, or the mixed-mode DLL references the C# assembly?  You can generate a `.netmodule` using the C# compiler, and the C++/CLI link.exe will happily merge that with the mixed-mode C++/CLI code.

Comment: Hi, ty for your answer. Is there a good way to create a .netmodule File?    csc.exe  /t:module for each .cs file (over 50) s a little bit long, but i cant find a special compileroption in vs (c#)

Comment: Some research shows that the Visual Studio build system, MSBUILD, supports building .netmodule files.  But there's no UI to configure that, you have to edit the .vcxproj in a text editor and change the `<OutputType>` setting to `module`.

Comment: Big thanks, works great! Creating .netmodule and then add "#using <PDFSharp.netmodule>" to the cpp project, remove the ref to the PDFSharp.dll and add "/link PDFSharp.netmodule /LTCG" to the commandline in c++!

Comment: Ok, I'll write up an answer explaining this approach.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605048/how-to-embed-a-dll-within-a-c-cli-executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++/CLI mixed-mode DLLs have two sets of references: the native imports in the PE header, and the .NET assembly references.  Problems finding the native imports will cause the symptom you observed, that loading the assembly fails early during load and cannot be intercepted and recovered.

It's not clear to me why the native dependency rules are applicable here.  For a true native dependency that needs to be located using an alternate search order under your control, delay-loading could be applied.  But that can't be used with a referenced .NET assembly.

In any case, the simplest fix is to not need a separate assembly at all.  Your goal is single file deployment, and the ideal single file deployment scenario is when all the code is contained in a single DLL and you don't need to unpack a second file at runtime.

For pure .NET assemblies, there is an ILMerge tool that combines multiple DLLs into a single file.  But your case has a C++/CLI mixed mode DLL, not pure MSIL.

Using multiple languages in a native program generally works a little bit differently.  Instead of producing a complete executable from each toolset, native code standardizes an object file format (Windows `.obj`, Linux `.o`) which all the various toolsets know how to produce, and then the link step can link together object files from a variety of languages.  The object files are often bundled into static libraries.  (A static library is just an archive of object files, with a symbol index)  Because the C++/CLI toolset is patterned on native C++, it uses this model as well.

The .NET version of this language-independent "object file" which can be further linked is a `.netmodule` file.  Internally, it is a .NET assembly without a manifest.  Functionally, it acts like a static library.  And the C++/CLI `link.exe` can link together C# (and VB, and F#, etc) `.netmodule` static libraries together with the C++/CLI object files and static libraries, and native object files and libraries, when it creates the mixed-mode assembly.

This isn't the most straightforward process, because while it is supported by the underlying toolchains, the Visual Studio project options dialog boxes don't have a UI for either creating or consuming `.netmodule` static libraries.

For the C# side to produce a `.netmodule`, you should open your `.csproj` file and change the `<OutputType>` setting to `module`.  Then reopen the project in Visual Studio and build as usual.

On the C++/CLI side, the project options dialog allows you to customize the compile and link command-lines.  Change the linker command to include `/link` and the name of the .netmodule file.

If you've done it right, the C++/CLI linker will create a single mixed-mode DLL with all the types and code from both the C# and C++/CLI source files.  And all the internal usage between C# and C++/CLI will be already resolved, so you won't have to worry about missing dependencies at run time.  Well, at least not *these* dependencies; any you didn't choose to link in will still be handled normally.